# How do I update a column with a NULL value in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have got a table which has thousands of rows and hundreds of columns. 
I need to insert NULL value in all the columns except THREE for FIRST 15 rows.
How do I approach with this problem statement?

I will provide with a small example below.
Ex.

```
ID   FirstNM    MiddleNM    LastNM    Gender    

1    John       H           Doe       M
2    Katie      F           Hopkins   F
3    Michelle   A           Slater    M
4    John       B           Kiwi      M
5    Alexander  C           Slander   M
6    Arda       D           Putin     M
7    Anuj       R           Trump     M
8    Priyanka   E           Moss      M
9    Hashim     F           George    M
10   Donald     G           Junior    M
11   Valdimir   W           Senior    M
12   Phoenix    Q           Cherkov   M
```

My output should look something like this.

```
ID   FirstNM    MiddleNM    LastNM    Gender    

1    NULL       NULL        NULL      NULL
2    NULL       NULL        NULL      NULL
3    NULL       NULL        NULL      NULL
4    NULL       NULL        NULL      NULL
5    NULL       NULL        NULL      NULL
6    Arda       D           Putin     M
7    Anuj       R           Trump     M
8    Priyanka   E           Moss      M
9    Hashim     F           George    M
10   Donald     G           Junior    M
11   Valdimir   W           Senior    M
12   Phoenix    Q           Cherkov   M
```

Comment: Do you mean for first 15 rows, you need to update all the columns to null value except first 3 columns i.e. FirstNM, MiddleNM, LastNM?

Comment: Yes. Just for representational purpose, I have written only 12 rows and have updated the values to NULL for the first 5 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the below update command -

```
UPDATE T
SET GENDER = NULL
   -- ,List all other columns assigning null value
WHERE ID <= 15;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But there are hundreds of columns. So, do I have to manually write all the column names?

Comment: You can either list all the columns manually or create a script to get all the column names from DBC.ColumnsV view, then update them.

Comment: You must look at - https://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/Dynamic-merge-into-statement/td-p/71357